Package in project, cannot preview SwiftUI in package
I have a normal UIKit project with a package dependency containing some SwiftUI. Opening the package on its own, I can preview the SwiftUI. However, when I have the package as a dependency, I get the dreaded message saying Active scheme does not build this file regardless of choosing the app or package scheme. Sometimes I just get the endless spinner.
Why can't I get a preview?
Using Xcode 16
